'selection_mode' not working in streamlit pills
I want to use streamlit pills to get the multiselect function
I tried using st.pills() and followed  streamlit-pills
options = ["North", "East", "South", "West"]
selection = st.pills("Directions", options, selection_mode="multi")
st.markdown(f"Your selected options: {selection}.")

AttributeError: module ‘streamlit’ has no attribute ‘pills’
Then to get about this I followed: streamlit-pills pypi
and then I did pip install streamlit-pills
from streamlit_pills import pills
selected = pills("Label", ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"], ["", "", ""])
st.write(selected)

In this mode streamlit pills work, but the selection_mode="multi" does not work in this option.
I even tried pip install streamlit-pills-multiselect, following streamlit-pills pypi multiselect but still no luck.

What's the Streamlit version you are using? st.pills() exists in 1.40.0 and not in the lower ones.

Please ensure you are using the Streamlit version 1.40.0.
st.pills() method does not exist in versions 1.39.0 and lower.

Yes I am using Streamlit version 1.40.0

That's strange. I did the whole thing in a fresh virtual environment - it's working fine. Are you sure there are no conflicting versions or virtual environments which might be causing this AttributeError?

Hi, yes, thanks. It works. I had previously installed Streamlit and was thinking it was version 1.40. However, version 1.39 was installed, so I removed the existing version and installed the new version 1.40.0, which worked. Thanks
